# How to externally execute a commands/scripts against the current scene rather than open a new blender window?

Tags: scripting

I am animator. My work consists of using 2D and 3D animtations together. For this reason, I recently installed blender soley for the grease pencil features.

I may exapnd my usage later on but right now I just want to get up and running.

I want to integrate blender into my existing toolset, so I can operate blender through the same interfaces I operate Maya and others tools with.

To do this, I essentially need a way to execute arbitrary Python code or blender commands externally.

The solutions I have across for Blender all lead to the creation of a new blender window when I execute them.

I want to target an already open blender scene, no different than manually invoking, say, `Edit` > `Undo` in a blender window.

In Maya I have a number of ways to do this. Command Ports being the ideal method.

Right now, I am really looking for quick and dirty way to get up and running. In Maya a quick way to execute externall `Mel` or `Python` code against an open scene is something like this:

```
Source "c:\temp\SomeCode.mel"
```

Then in Maya define a hotkey to run the above code. Then through AutoHokey/PowerShell change the contents of the `SomeCode.mel` file and then trigger the hotkey. The code will be triggred in Maya as if it were manually invoked.

I am open to whatever method will get the job done. Thanks for any help.